# Toggle Two Things Separately React Constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to toggle two different dropdown menus and can't seem to get it working. New to react and have probably been looking at it too long and it's something simple. The problem is when I toggle one the other gets toggled as well, so they both show.. Here is what I have:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "./component/link";
import styles from "./header.module.css";

class Header extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super ( props )    
    this.state = {
      show : false
    }
    this.toggleBusiness = this.toggleBusiness.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      show : false
    }
    this.togglePersonal = this.togglePersonal.bind(this);
  }

  toggleBusiness = () => {
    const { show } = this.state;
    this.setState( { show : !show } )
  }

  togglePersonal = () => {
    const { show } = this.state;
    this.setState( { show : !show } )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.topNav} >
        <div className="grid">
          <div className="grid-cell">
            <div className={ styles.logoText }>
              Logo
            </div>
          </div>  
          <nav>
            <div className="grid-cell">
              <ul className="list-unstyled">
                <li><Link to={'/design'}>About</Link></li>
                <li><a onClick={this.toggleBusiness}>Business</a></li>                  
                <li><a onClick={this.toggleBusiness}>Personal</a></li>
                <li><Link to={'/posts'}>Blog</Link></li>
                <li><Link to={'/contact'}>Contact</Link></li>
                <li className={styles.menuButton}><a className="button button-secondary" href="tel:2252931086">File a Claim</a></li>
                <li className={styles.menuButton}><a className="button" href="/">Get Insurance</a></li>
              </ul>              
            </div> 
          </nav>
        </div>
        { this.state.show && <BusinessDropdown /> }
        { this.state.show && <PersonalDropdown /> }
      </div>
    )}
}

class BusinessDropdown extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown">BusinessTest</div>
    )
  }
}
class PersonalDropdown extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown">PersonalTest</div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header;
```

So basically I want it to toggle the Business Dropdown one when I click Business and the Personal Dropdown when I press Personal. Also, if you have something that would work better than this approach let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `toggleBusiness` and `togglePersonal` to this:

```
toggleBusiness = () => {
  const { show } = this.state;
  this.setState({ show: show === "business" ? null : "business" });
};

togglePersonal = () => {
  const { show } = this.state;
  this.setState({ show: show === "personal" ? null : "personal" });
};
```

then in the conditional rendering, do this:

```
{this.state.show === "business" && <BusinessDropdown />}
{this.state.show === "personal" && <PersonalDropdown />}
```

...also in your links, you have this:

```
<li><a onClick={this.toggleBusiness}>Business</a></li>                  
<li><a onClick={this.toggleBusiness}>Personal</a></li>
```

Where you should have this:

```
<li><a onClick={this.toggleBusiness}>Business</a></li>                  
<li><a onClick={this.togglePersonal}>Personal</a></li>
```

**Edit:** I realise this is not quite what you asked for - this toggles business off when personal is switched on. Personally I think this approach would actually suit better given the fact you're opening a new dropdown menu, you will probably want the other one to close.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.state.show` for both Business and Personal.
Adding a second state variable like `showBusiness` and `showPersonal`
should solve your problem.

Also you can/should declare your state only once with

```
this.state = {
  showBusiness: false,
  showPersonal: false
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you set `this.state.show` to false **2 times** separate this into two separate variables, perhaps `this.state.showBuisness` and `this.state.showPersonal`?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be something like this.

*1. set initial state*

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    business: false,
    personal: false
  }
}
```

*2. Create ONE function to update both status.*

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    [e.target.id]: !prevState[e.target.id]
  } 
}
```

*3. Add function to the onclick AND an id*

```
<button id="personal" onClick={this.handleClick}>SHOW PERSONAL</button>
```